# Scoreboard system, php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I looked into many, many guides into how to make numbered navigation links after results exceed, let's say 25 results, so the url bar would have a similar url ./index.php?page=3, and couldn't find something easy to implement according to my code:

```
        <body>
    <div id = 'scoreboardcontainer'>
<?php
    $ranking = mysql_query("SELECT username, points\n"
    . "FROM sector0_players\n"
    . "WHERE points = (SELECT MAX(points) FROM sector0_players WHERE points< (SELECT MAX(points) FROM sector0_players WHERE points <(SELECT MAX(points) FROM sector0_players)))");
?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#scoreboard" title = "Point scoreboards">Scoreboards</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tour_boards" title = "Tournament socreboards" class = "tbr">Tournament</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="scoreboard">
                <div class = "scoreboardtitles">
                    <div class = "player_score_rankinfl2">Rank</div>
                    <div class = "player_score_usnamefl2">Username</div>
                    <div class = "player_score_charnamefl2">Character</div>
                    <div class = "player_score_pointfl2">Points</div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <hr />
            <?php
    $scoreboardquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sector0_players ORDER BY points DESC");
    while($scoreboard_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($scoreboardquery)){
?>
                <div class="global_container_score_class"> <!--Start generating from here-->
                    <div class = "scoreboard_1l">
                            <div class = "player_rank">1st</div>
                            <div class = "player_name"><a href = "profile.php?id=<?php echo $scoreboard_fetch['id'];?>"><?php echo $scbdname = $scoreboard_fetch['username'];?></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "scoreboard_2r">
                            <div class = "player_charname"><?php echo $scbddspname = $scoreboard_fetch['displayname'];?></div>
                            <div class = "player_points"><?php echo $scbdpoints = number_format($scoreboard_fetch['points']);?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
```

I am not experienced in OOP, I know how to program it, but not to modify it to meet my needs. If this case requires OOP I would be grateful if someone would provide me a good start to learning advanced OO.
If not, just type in what I need to achieve (no code is required unless necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're talking about pagination - something that doesn't necessarily require OOP. If you're interested in learning from scratch, a search for "php pagination" will yield tons of information :]

Comment: I am really sorry for my hurry to post the question. I found a good set of tutorials by just searching for "pagination" keyword. Many many thanks.

Comment: @Khalid - No problem, the desire to learn it yourself is quite admirable :]